# ProgressDialog while loading data

Tags: java, android

I am encountering a problem in my Android application.  I am creating a currency converter.  I need to create a progressdialog that appears when you convert a value from one currency to another.

Here is part of my code:

```
        if (text1.equals("US Dollar - USD") && text2.equals("Euro - EUR") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length()==0) {
            dialog1 = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "Calculating...");
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try{
                    convertvalues("USD", "EUR");
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        edittexteuros.setText("Error");
                    }

                }
            });
            thread.start();
        }
private Handler handler = new Handler () {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case 0:
        dialog1.dismiss();
        break;
        }
    }
};
```

The progressdialog comes up and goes away, but nothing happens in the background.  Here are a few pics of what my app looks like:

[image: Before ProgressDialog]

This is before the progressdialog comes.

When I press calculate:

[image: When I press calculate]

After the progressdialog finishes:

[image: After the progressdialog goes]

As you can see, after the progressdialog goes away, my values don't convert.

In my code,

```
convertvalues("USD", "EUR");
```

just gets actual currency value from the internet and multiplies it with the value in my edittext.  There is nothing wrong with it and it worked without the progressdialog.  I have tested it many times myself.

What am I doing wrong here?  I have checked Google for over a week, but I could not find a single solution.  Any help regarding this problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where are you updating the `EditText`?

Answer (score 0):

Just like how you update your progressdialog in a handler, you must also update EditTexts in the handler (as it must run on the UI thread). So ideally you would return the result from convertvalues and then pass it to the handler via a message.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, your code is fine but you aren't updating the TextView/EditText values when you dismiss the dialog. This means that although it looks like nothing is happening, it actually is - you just aren't updating to see the results.

So, assuming `convertvalues()` has the converted values stored somewhere, before you call `dismiss()` you should set your TextViews based on those values.

Answer (score 0):

you can use asynctask in android

see following code may be it will help you..

```
private class asyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> 
    {
        Context context;
        ProgressDialog pd;

        asyncTask(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context; 
            pd = new ProgressDialog(activityContext);

        } 
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            pd.setTitle("Loading..");
            pd.setMessage("Please wait ...");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();
        } 
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
        {
            if(pd.isShowing()) pd.dismiss();
        } 

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {
            convertvalues();

            return boolean_value;
        }
}
```

And Just Call this asynctask with

```
new asyncTask(Your_Context).execute();
```